# Remove portion of the string before compare with existent values

Tags: php, algorithm, comparison, string-comparison

I have an array coming with the following structure:

```
$arr = [
     traveler_name_1 => 'value',
     hotel_name_1    => 'value',
     hotel_in_date_1 => 'value',

     traveler_name_2 => 'value',
     hotel_name_2    => 'value',
     hotel_in_date_2 => 'value',

     traveler_name_n => 'value',
     hotel_name_n    => 'value',
     hotel_in_date_n => 'value',
];
```

I want to check if the string without the index is valid and is allowed. For example:

```
$allowed_values = [
    'traveler_name',
    'hotel_name',
    'hotel_in_date'
];
```

The easy way would be iterate over `$arr` as `$key => $value` pairs and then make an `in_array()` but for do that I need to remove first the last portion of the string, for example:

```
traveler_name_1 => remove the _1
hotel_name_1    => remove the _1
hotel_in_date_1 => remove the _1
```

So I can look for them on the `$allowed_values` array.

So the question is how do I remove that part from the string?

The values after the second `_` are generated dynamically so they hasn't a constant length. The value before are constant.

If you have a better way to validate this then go ahead and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (probably not the most efficient one) is to do this:

```
$s = "traveler_name_24872";
$arr = explode("_", $s);
array_pop($arr);
$s2 = implode("_", $arr); // traveler_name
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you want to manipulate the data, this would return what you're looking for. You could then put the $index and $value in a new array or just manipulate the data from within that foreach loop.

This returns the full string minus the last two characters (via the -2). If you want to return all but the last 3 characters, you'd replace -2 with -3, etc.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   $index = substr($key, 0, -2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution after some tries so here it's what I was looking for:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array(substr(key($key), 0, strrpos(key($key), '_')), $allowed_values, true)) { 
        echo 'Not allowed'; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you anyway